# My pc works at high performance due to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, services, preferences, pae, gnome-settings-daemon

I have a dell pc. It is have two graphics card (4100 and 7730m). I used solves on internet sites but then borders and desktop menu disappers. Sorry for bad English. Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you have an ATI radeon 7470m if I'm not wrong... and I asume you have installed the privative drivers, so what you should try is remove them.

First, go to one of the virtual terminals pressing Ctrl+Alt+F6

Log in and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

It will ask you for your password and a confirmation. When it's done, you will need to reboot the computer. You don't need to go back to the desktop, just in the same terminal, type:

```
sudo reboot
```

When you get back to the login screen, log in and your desktop should be working fine with the default drivers (xserver-xorg-vide-ati).

Good luck!

Comment: Removing the superior fglrx drivers instead of solving the issue? Wow.

Comment: Superior, the drivers that let you stuck with a wallpaper and no gui? Wow wow....

Comment: fglrx vs ati. Did you use them both? A "somewhat decent" driver with GL and proper acceleration, and a crappy FOSS "driver" that turns your PC/laptop into a volcano. I understand that he had problems with the proprietary driver, but those issues should be troubleshooted, instead of making a hairdryer out of his laptop.

Comment: Yes, I did use them both. In fact, after many tests I'm using the fglrx now. And yes, I know fglrx is far better... when it works. At least with the "crappy" foss you have a desktop, and you can do more troubleshooting from there...